# Projective modules and nondegenerate pairings

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

Let $M$ be a finitely-generated projective module over a commutative algebra $A$, defined over $\mathbb{R}$. Consider a nondegenerate bilinear pairing 
$$
(*,*):M \times M \to A,
$$
where by **nondegenerate** we mean that, for all non-zero $m \in M$, there exists some $n \in M$, such that 
$$
(m,n) \neq 0.
$$

Does there exist an isomorphism
$$
\phi:M \to M^*
$$
such that 
$$
(m,n) = \phi(m)(n),
$$
for all $m,n \in M$?

A side question, is: is projectivity necessary for us to 
establish such an isomorphism, or can it be established in a weaker setting?

Comment: Do you assume that your module is of finite type? Otherwise you have counter-examples with vector spaces of infinite dimension.

Comment: @Captain Lama: Yes, we are assuming that $M$ is finitely generated.

Answer (score 4):

No; for instance, if $A=M=\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $(m,n)=xmn$ then $\phi: M\to M^*\cong M$ is the map $\phi(m)=xm$ which is not an isomorphism.

More generally, $\phi(m)(n)=(m,n)$ defines a homomorphism $M\to M^*$ for any bilinear form on a module $M$, and nondegeneracy just says that $\phi$ is injective.  In general there is no reason to think $\phi$ is surjective, though.

Comment: The assumption is that $A$ is an algebra, not a general ring.

Comment: Can this problem, i.e. non-surjectivity, happen for algebras?

Comment: Any ring is an algebra, for instance over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I am interested in algebras over fields.